# Shell script runs when using the command: ./script, but not the command: script, where PATH=.:'usr/bin':etc

Tags: node.js, shell, zsh

I'm running Zsh, with my current directory in my path, but the script doesn't run when used without `./`

Read these statements executed in my terminal to understand the context (the `»` is my shell prompt character):

```
» ls
Makefile node_modules  package.json  README.md  src test  tst
» echo $PATH
.:[all_my_other_directories]
» cat test
echo "test";
nodeunit tst/
» ./test                                                                                                                                               
test
OK: 2 assertions (1ms)
» test
» which test
./test
```

Notice that on the `which test` points to the right spot, but `test` doesn't run it.

I know that putting my local directory in front of my path is a bad idea, but I've changed the path to having `.` at the end and it doesn't change anything.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Putting current (`.`, not any static local) or relative to current directory into `$PATH` is a bad idea always, no matter whether you have it in front or at the tail (though latter is a bit safer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword `test` is reserved because it is actually a shell builtin. To compound the confusion, there is also a shell *command* also called `test`.

Use a different name instead =)

Comment: Ah i see; I assumed that the only two options were `/usr/bin/test` (the one you mentioned) and the one I had in my directory. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

@sampson-chen is completely right. One addition: to check what exactly you will run use

```
type test
```

, it will give you

```
test is a shell builtin
```

and thus resolve the problem. Don’t use `which`, it always looks for a command. `type` is equivalent to `whence -v` thus you can use the former instead.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information! I'll definitely use `type` for my finding needs!